# Error running '__rvm_make -j8' in MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Now my ruby version is 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin16]

But my teachers in university ask us to install 2.3.1, so I have tried `rvm install 2.3.1` but it reports

> Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
>
> please read /Users/mac/.rvm/log/1508247055_ruby-2.3.1/make.log There
> has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

There is the make.log

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
> Referenced from: /Users/mac/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.1/./miniruby   Expected
> in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat   Referenced from:
> /Users/mac/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.1/./miniruby   Expected in:
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: How did you install 2.4.2? Did you use `rvm` for that too? Could you run `which rvm` and report back? `which ruby`?

Comment: yeah, and I have solved the problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason that is a bug of newest Xcode.

Probably because the font or coding format is not compatible, so if you try

```
xcode-select --install
```

and continue to try your install command

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

It may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
brew install openssl
rvm install 2.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while install ruby 2.5.1, Error running '__rvm_make -j8' ,

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the `xcode-select` command, what does it do? What is the `--switch` option? Why does the user need `sudo` to run it?

Comment: The command sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer is used to change the active developer directory used by the command line tools in macOS.

The command starts with sudo which is short for "superuser do" and is used to run the command with superuser privileges (e.g. with root permissions).

The command xcode-select is a command-line utility on macOS that manages the active developer directory used by the command-line developer tools such as gcc, make, and clang.

Comment: The --switch flag is used to set the active developer directory to the one specified after it, in this case /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. This is the default location of the Xcode developer tools and where most users will have them installed.

This command is typically used when you have multiple versions of Xcode installed on your machine, and you want to switch between them and use different versions of the command line tools. It is also used when you have installed Xcode command line tools separately and want to set the correct path for it.

Comment: It is important to note that running this command with sudo will require you to enter your admin password, and it's not recommended to use the command unless you are aware of the consequences.